# Rate Equations for Simulation

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, laser, simulations, software

I would like to simulate a passively Q-switched laser with MATLAB. Do you have any suggestions - or link to literature/paper - which rate equations I should use? It would be nice if the equations include multi longitudinal modes and a spatial dependence to implement the spatial hole burning.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the rate equation given here:

Numerical Simulation of Passively Q-Switched Solid State Lasers, I. Lăncrănjan, R. Savastru, D. Savastru and S. Micloş, DOI: 10.5772/47812

and also check google scholar, there are plenty of articles that will suit your need.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and the suggestion. I’ll read the aforementioned paper and try to simulate the problem.